# If a hash map is a list of keys and values, what is just a list of unique keys called (no values)?

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

What is the terminology used for a no-value unique list?

I need to keep track of a very large list (billions) of 6 char unique strings. My application will need to search the list to see if a string exists, and if it doesn't then insert it, hopefully with the lowest latency possibly.

This would need to be stored locally and persist to disk.

I've tried using leveldb, kyoto cabinet, and gdbm but once the list gets large the latency is way to slow.

Comment: Regarding the question in the title, it sounds like you're talking about a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: Regarding the question in the body, it sounds like you want to look at [ordered trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), which could, in a simple case, be implemented as a directory structure on disk.

Comment: You might find a trie works; it might be too expensive on memory.  Are your strings text strings or byte strings (how big is the alphabet in the strings)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Byte strings and the alphabet is 63 chars. Is there a library you would recommend?

Comment: I'm not aware of published trie libraries.  I can offer what's available from my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub in the [src/tries](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/tries) sub-directory.  There are links to various answers — so-3994-9116 is perhaps the most interesting.  But they're toy programs; moderately high quality, but still basically toys.